# MonoTorrent C# Downloading torrent

Tags: c#, bittorrent, torrent, monotorrent

I'm creating a torrent application.I found a library called "MonoTorrent" which i decided to use.There is some problems this code below doesnt work.I think a lot of code are changed like  `ITorrentManager`  doesn't exist also for  `EngineSettings engineSettings = EngineSettings.DefaultSettings;` DefaultSettings doesn't exists.If anyone can help me to make this work i tried a lot of codes for mono torrent but no one works.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // An ITorrentManager is passed out of the engine when you load a torrent. This is
        // used for controlling the torrent.
        ITorrentManager torrentManager;

        // These are the default settings for the engine for this session
        EngineSettings engineSettings = EngineSettings.DefaultSettings;

        // The default location to download files to on your HardDrive, like a downloads folder
        // All files will be downloaded using this as the base directory. Single file torrents will
        // go directly into this directory, multifile torrents will create a directory within this
        // and download there.
        engineSettings.DefaultSavePath = @"D:\Downloads\Torrents";

        // Maximum upload speed of 30 kB/sec. At upload speeds of less than 5kB/sec, there will
        // be automatic download speed limiting to 5x the selected upload.
        engineSettings.GlobalMaxUploadSpeed = 30;

        // Every torrent loaded into the engine for this session will start off with these default settings
        // unless other settings are specified.
        TorrentSettings torrentSettings = TorrentSettings.DefaultSettings;

        // Each torrent will be allowed a max of 10kB/sec upload speed
        torrentSettings.MaxUploadSpeed = 10;

        // Each torrent will have 4 upload slots to allow 2.5kB/sec per slot.
        torrentSettings.UploadSlots = 4;

        // Instantiate a new engine with the engineSettings and Default Torrent settings.
        ClientEngine engine = new ClientEngine(engineSettings, torrentSettings);

        // A torrent can be downloaded from the specified url, saved to the specified file and
        // then loaded into the engine.
        // torrentManager =engine.LoadTorrent(new Uri("http://example.com/example.torrent"), @"D:\Downloads\example.torrent");

        // Alternatively a .torrent can just be loaded from the disk. This torrent will save
        // to the DefaultSaveLocation as specified in the EngineSettings and will inherit the
        // default settings that are set in the Engine.
        //torrentManager = engine.LoadTorrent(@"D:\Downloads\Torrents\MyTorrentFile.torrent");

        // This torrent would use the supplied settings instead of using the ones that were
        // supplied when instantiating the engine
        torrentManager = engine.LoadTorrent(@"D:\Downloads\Torrents\MyTorrentFile.torrent", TorrentSettings.DefaultSettings);

        // If you have loaded multiple torrents into the engine, you can start them all at once with this:
        // engine.Start();

        // Or you can start one specific torrent by passing in that torrents ITorrentManager
        engine.Start(torrentManager);

        // You can hook into various events in order to display information on screen:
        // Fired every time a peer is added through DHT, PEX or Tracker Updates
        torrentManager.OnPeersAdded+=new EventHandler<PeersAddedEventArgs>(PeersAdded);

        // Fired every time a piece is hashed
        torrentManager.OnPieceHashed+=new EventHandler<PieceHashedEventArgs>(PieceHashed);

        // Fired every time the torrent State changes (i.e. paused/hashing/downloading)
        torrentManager.OnTorrentStateChanged+= new EventHandler<TorrentStateChangedEventArgs>(torrentStateChanged);

        // Fired every time a piece changes. i.e. block sent/received/written to disk
        torrentManager.PieceManager.OnPieceChanged+=new EventHandler<PieceEventArgs>(pieceStateChanged);

        // Fired every time a connection is either created or destroyed
        ClientEngine.connectionManager.OnPeerConnectionChanged+=new EventHandler<PeerConnectionEventArgs>(peerConnectionChanged);

        // Fired every time a peer message is sent
        ClientEngine.connectionManager.OnPeerMessages+= new EventHandler<PeerMessageEventArgs>(peerMessageSentOrRecieved);

        // Keep running while the torrent isn't stopped or paused.
        while (torrentManager.State != TorrentState.Stopped && torrentManager.State != TorrentState.Paused)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(torrentManager.Progress());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            if (torrentManager.Progress() == 100.0)
            {
                // If we want to stop a torrent, or the engine for whatever reason, we call engine.Stop()
                // A tracker update *must* be performed before the engine is shut down, so you must
                // wait for the waithandle to become signaled before continuing with the complete
                // shutdown of your client. Otherwise stats will not get reported correctly.
                WaitHandle[] handles = engine.Stop();
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a library that was [abandoned more than 10 years ago](https://www.mono-project.com/archived/monotorrent) doesn’t seem like the best plan

Comment: Do you have any other ideas how i can download torrent? Do you know for other nuget packages?

Comment: What about this one? https://github.com/amacal/leak

Comment: MonoTorrent isn't actual to use. You should look for other, freshy libs or try to fork MonoTorrent by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource ();

    var task = MainAsync (args, cancellation.Token);

    // We need to cleanup correctly when the user closes the window by using ctrl-c
    // or an unhandled exception happens
    Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate { cancellation.Cancel (); task.Wait (); };
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += delegate { cancellation.Cancel (); task.Wait (); };
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += delegate (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine (e.ExceptionObject); cancellation.Cancel (); task.Wait (); };
    Thread.GetDomain ().UnhandledException += delegate (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine (e.ExceptionObject); cancellation.Cancel (); task.Wait (); };

    task.Wait ();
}
```

```
static async Task MainAsync (string[] args, CancellationToken token)
{
    // Give an example of how settings can be modified for the engine.
    var settingBuilder = new EngineSettingsBuilder {
        // Allow the engine to automatically forward ports using upnp/nat-pmp (if a compatible router is available)
        AllowPortForwarding = true,

        // Automatically save a cache of the DHT table when all torrents are stopped.
        AutoSaveLoadDhtCache = true,

        // Automatically save 'FastResume' data when TorrentManager.StopAsync is invoked, automatically load it
        // before hash checking the torrent. Fast Resume data will be loaded as part of 'engine.AddAsync' if
        // torrent metadata is available. Otherwise, if a magnetlink is used to download a torrent, fast resume
        // data will be loaded after the metadata has been downloaded. 
        AutoSaveLoadFastResume = true,

        // If a MagnetLink is used to download a torrent, the engine will try to load a copy of the metadata
        // it's cache directory. Otherwise the metadata will be downloaded and stored in the cache directory
        // so it can be reloaded later.
        AutoSaveLoadMagnetLinkMetadata = true,

        // Use a fixed port to accept incoming connections from other peers.
        ListenPort = 55123,

        // Use a random port for DHT communications.
        DhtPort = 55123,
    };
    using var engine = new ClientEngine (settingBuilder.ToSettings ());

    Task task;
    if (args.Length == 1 && args[0] == "--vlc") {
        task = new VLCStream (engine).StreamAsync (InfoHash.FromHex ("AEE0F0082CC2F449412C1DD8AF4C58D9AAEE4B5C"), token);
    } else if (args.Length == 1 && MagnetLink.TryParse (args[0], out MagnetLink link)) {
        task = new MagnetLinkStreaming (engine).DownloadAsync (link, token);
    } else {
        task = new StandardDownloader (engine).DownloadAsync (token);
    }

    if (engine.Settings.AllowPortForwarding)
        Console.WriteLine ("uPnP or NAT-PMP port mappings will be created for any ports needed by MonoTorrent");

    try {
        await task;
    } catch (OperationCanceledException) {

    }

    foreach (var manager in engine.Torrents) {
        var stoppingTask = manager.StopAsync ();
        while (manager.State != TorrentState.Stopped) {
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} is {1}", manager.Torrent.Name, manager.State);
            await Task.WhenAll (stoppingTask, Task.Delay (250));
        }
        await stoppingTask;
        if (engine.Settings.AutoSaveLoadFastResume)
            Console.WriteLine ($"FastResume data for {manager.Torrent?.Name ?? manager.InfoHash.ToHex ()} has been written to disk.");
    }

    if (engine.Settings.AutoSaveLoadDhtCache)
        Console.WriteLine ($"DHT cache has been written to disk.");

    if (engine.Settings.AllowPortForwarding)
        Console.WriteLine ("uPnP and NAT-PMP port mappings have been removed");
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/alanmcgovern/monotorrent/blob/master/src/SampleClient/main.cs

Comment: the folder stample client content the code about has you can run the torrent.

Comment: if you see the method public async Task DownloadAsync (CancellationToken token) in the class StandarDownloader you understand how use it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).